# Display username after login

Tags: php

im trying to display the username after login but i dont know how to do that..
Here is my login form..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="simplestyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="divOne">
    <h1>Login</h1>

    <form action="simple2.php" method="post">
        <table style="width:60%">
            <tr>
                <td class="colm1"><b>Name:</b></td>
                <td class="colm2"><input type="text" name="username"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="colm1"><b>Password:</b></td>
                <td class="colm2"><input type="password" name="password"></td>
            </tr>
            </table><br>
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Post!" class="buttonLog"> <br />
    </form>
</div><br>

    </body>
    </html>
```

And here is my connection for login ..i named the php file to simple2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['login'])){
    $_SESSION['uname'] = 'username';
    $filename = "accounts.txt";
    $uname=$_POST['username'];
    $pwd=$_POST['password'];
    $admin= 'hanna';
    $adminPass= '2302';
    if (file_exists($filename)) {

        $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
        $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
        $contents = file_get_contents($filename);
        $contents = explode("\n", $contents);

    if ($uname == $admin && $pwd == $adminPass){
        header('Location: hometry.php');

    }
    elseif ($uname == $uname && $pwd == $uname) {
        echo "member";
    }

    else{
        echo "Username and Password is not registered!";
    }
 }
}

fclose($handle);
?>
```

after login, i want the username to be displayed on homepage but i don't what to do in the code. Can someone help me?

Comment: I wasn't the down-voter, but it sounds like you're simply looking for `echo $uname`. Though note that you **really** shouldn't be using a `.txt` as a database...

Comment: i tried that before but it doesnt work also :(

Answer (score 1):

since you have assigned $_SESSION['uname'] = 'username' in simple2.php, then in hometry.php you call the variable by using

```
<?php
session_start();
$uname = $_SESSION['uname'];
?>
```

but from your code, you need to put

```
$uname=$_POST['username'];
```

before

```
$_SESSION['uname'] = 'username';
```

and assign $uname to $_SESSION['uname'] else it will always display 'username'
or you can pass the username as a URL variable

```
header('Location: hometry.php?uname='.$uname);
```

so your modified code will look like this for option 1

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['login'])){
    $filename = "accounts.txt";
    $uname=$_POST['username'];
    $_SESSION['uname'] = $uname;
    $pwd=$_POST['password'];
    $admin= 'hanna';
    $adminPass= '2302';
    if (file_exists($filename)) {

        $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
        $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
        $contents = file_get_contents($filename);
        $contents = explode("\n", $contents);

    if ($uname == $admin && $pwd == $adminPass){
        header('Location: hometry.php');

    }
    elseif ($uname == $uname && $pwd == $uname) {
        echo "member";
    }

    else{
        echo "Username and Password is not registered!";
    }
 }
}

fclose($handle);
?>
```

and this for option 2

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['login'])){
    $filename = "accounts.txt";
    $uname=$_POST['username'];
    $pwd=$_POST['password'];
    $admin= 'hanna';
    $adminPass= '2302';
    if (file_exists($filename)) {

        $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
        $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
        $contents = file_get_contents($filename);
        $contents = explode("\n", $contents);

    if ($uname == $admin && $pwd == $adminPass){
        header('Location: hometry.php?uname='.$uname);

    }
    elseif ($uname == $uname && $pwd == $uname) {
        echo "member";
    }

    else{
        echo "Username and Password is not registered!";
    }
 }
}

fclose($handle);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right after you check if the user is in your accounts.txt file, put the username in a session.

```
$_SESSION['uname'] = $uname;
```

To call the username in your homepage.php:

```
<?php
    // Start the session
    session_start();

    // call the username
    echo $_SESSION['uname'];
?>
```

Comment: it says "
Notice: Undefined index: uname in C:\xampp\htdocs\Awep Tutorial 1\PHP\Assignment2\hometry.php on line 6"